# Change application settings through settings bundle while application is running IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have written code in -(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application , but my application is not detecting the change made in the settings bundle, new settings work when application restarts, someone please help me how to make changes in application's settings while application is running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to `-(BOOL)synchronize;` the `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: you are welcome, if my answer fits your needs, accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left ;)

Answer (score 1):

After setting the values in `NSUserDefaults` try calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` so that the values get written to disk.

Answer (score 0):

in your applicationWillEnterForeground: methode after this line

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults], add this line

[defaults synchronize];